# How to rename a subset of rownames based on information from a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find a code that allows me to change a subset of rownames selected based on criteria from a column. As an example using the mtcars dataset, I would like to add a character behind (_1) in all rownames that satisfy "df$gear values == 4" and leave the rownames as it is for those that do not satisfy.

```
df <- mtcars
head(df)
```

I have tried the below to paste _1 to all rownames.

```
rownames(df) <- paste0(rownames(df), "_1")
```

I know you can do the below to change a single rowname.

```
rownames(df)[rownames(df) == "Merc 280"] <- "Some Mercedes"
```

And I tried to juggle with these codes to do what is described above and came up with the below.

```
rownames(df)[df$gear == "4"] <- paste(rownames(df), "_1")
```

But this code throws an error - "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". I understand the error message but I'm not sure of an alternate code to make it work.

I would appreciate any feedback, comments or thoughts.

Thanks,
Cathy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" because you subset 12 rownames (for which `gear == 4`), but you want to assign 32 rownames to it (`paste(rownames(df), "_1")`). The trick is to also subset the rownames you want to change, because you only want to change the rownames that belong to rows for which the condition `gear == 4` is true.

Try this:

```
df <- mtcars
rownames(df)[df$gear == 4] <- paste0(rownames(df)[df$gear == 4], "_1")
rownames(df)
 [1] "Mazda RX4_1"         "Mazda RX4 Wag_1"     "Datsun 710_1"        "Hornet 4 Drive"      "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"            
 [7] "Duster 360"          "Merc 240D_1"         "Merc 230_1"          "Merc 280_1"          "Merc 280C_1"         "Merc 450SE"         
[13] "Merc 450SL"          "Merc 450SLC"         "Cadillac Fleetwood"  "Lincoln Continental" "Chrysler Imperial"   "Fiat 128_1"         
[19] "Honda Civic_1"       "Toyota Corolla_1"    "Toyota Corona"       "Dodge Challenger"    "AMC Javelin"         "Camaro Z28"         
[25] "Pontiac Firebird"    "Fiat X1-9_1"         "Porsche 914-2"       "Lotus Europa"        "Ford Pantera L"      "Ferrari Dino"       
[31] "Maserati Bora"       "Volvo 142E_1"
```

Please note: in general it is a bit nicer to give the rownames their own column, because then you can just use the same syntax to access them as you use for the other columns.

Comment: Just to reply to one of your comments, I would have made the rownames their own column but I am trying to apply this code to single cell RNAseq dataset and that itself causes other issues downstream. How do I accept? (apologies. This is my first post and still learning how to use stack overflow)

Comment: @Cathy Yes, I know, there are still some functions out there that rely on rownames (e.g. correlation plots), so one should know how to deal with rownames. On the other hand, in the `tidyverse` they don't like rownames